# Delete schema from Bigquery with python client

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to remove schema from table with python, but I get error.

```
table.schema = (
    bigquery.SchemaField('Name', 'STRING'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Age', 'INTEGER'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('Weight', 'FLOAT'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('TEST', 'FLOAT'),
)
table.schema.remove('TEST')
table.update()
```

It returns an error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

How can I remove unwanted schemas from table?

Answer (score 1):

I think table.schema is a list of `SchemaField`, not a dictionary, so `remove('TEST')` won't work.
Maybe something like this instead:

```
table.schema = [field for field in table.schema if field.name != 'TEST']
```